# How can I deploy an asp.net mvc2 app developed on SharpDevelop (windows 7 64bit) to the local iis 7.5?

Tags: iis, permissions, sharpdevelop

I'm using SharpDevelop and can test/see the app using  "Use IIS Express Web Server" selected in the project property. But when I try to change to "Use local IIS Web Server" and hit "Create application/virtual directory", an error message show up that said:

> ```
> Filename: redirection.config
> Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
> ```

At end, what I need is deploy MVC 2 app to a IIS Server, first to a local server and then to a remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved running SharpDevelop as Admin.